# Facebook iFrame form POST submit will cause a new window to open

Tags: php, facebook, forms, submit

I've got a PHP Facebook application that's running in an iFrame, and under https.  When the user of my app submits a form, the results pop up in a new window.  This isn't the desired behavior.  When I ran this under http, I didn't run into this problem.  On the form tag, I had set the target to go back to the iframe_canvas, but is that still the right place to send this to?  target="iframe_canvas".

How have any of you set up a FB app to submit form information under https?

Comment: Did you try just leaving the target off completely?

Comment: That's something I'm going to try tonight!  In the old way that it was done, that was needed to force the form to go back to the iframe window that the form was submitted under.  I'll take it off on one of my forms and see what happens.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: That worked under FF and Chrome, got to get IE and Safari working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removal of the target off of this, along with a number of other changes to the configuration of the application, including the addition of a name space, and changing of the canvas URLs in the app configuration caused this to work.  Thanks for the help!